# the input text box focus is getting exited while navigating to the second page react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using:

```
"react-bootstrap-table-next": "4.0.3",
"react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
"react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.3",
```

I am using input text in my row, here is the code:

```
const [focusedRowIndex, setFocusedRowIndex] = useState(null);

// ...

{
  dataField: "newCredit",
  text: "new Credit",
  headerAlign: "center",
  align: "center",
  formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={cell}
        onChange={(e) =>
          formatExtraData.handleCreditChange(rowIndex, e.target.value)
        }
        onFocus={() => formatExtraData.handleFocusChange(rowIndex)}
        onClick={() => formatExtraData.handleFocusChange(rowIndex)}
        autoFocus={rowIndex === focusedRowIndex}
      />
    );
  },
  formatExtraData: {
    handleCreditChange: (rowIndex, value) => {
      const newUserList = [...userList];
      newUserList[rowIndex].newCredit = value;
      setUserList(newUserList);
    },
    handleFocusChange: (rowIndex) => {
      console.log(rowIndex);
      setFocusedRowIndex(rowIndex);
    },
  },
};
```

This input box is working fine on the first page, but when navigating to the second page whatever I am writing in the input box is also showing the value in the first page input box.

I want the input text to work similarly to how it is working on the first page.

Comment: Please give a solution i have tried but it is working fine on  first page but not working properly on  second page

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the user to modify by using `rowIndex`, but that `rowIndex` is scoped to the page you are on. On page two, the top item has a `rowIndex` of `0` just like the top item on page one also has a `rowIndex` of `0`. Because of that, each cell on each row of a page is also editing the cell that happens to be in that same position across all other pages.

The way you get around this is by avoiding using the `rowIndex` as an identifier for the row because as you have discovered **it is not actually unique** and you absolutely need a unique & stable identifier for the row, that (crucially) is unique across **all** pages.

Items in your `userList` should have an `id` property or another unique identifier, assuming that is coming from some external source like the server. I'm assuming that's your use case, but if this list is instead being constructed entirely on the client side, you should assign some client-side generated `id` to each item in the array.

You would then use this to lookup the right item in the array to edit. Below, I am assuming that each entry in `usersList` already has an `id`.

```
const [focusedRowId, setFocusedRowId] = useState(null);

// ...

{
  dataField: "newCredit",
  text: "new Credit",
  headerAlign: "center",
  align: "center",
  formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={cell}
        onChange={(e) =>
          formatExtraData.handleCreditChange(row.id, e.target.value)
        }
        onFocus={() => formatExtraData.handleFocusChange(row.id)}
        onClick={() => formatExtraData.handleFocusChange(row.id)}
        autoFocus={row.id === focusedRowId}
      />
    );
  },
  formatExtraData: {
    handleCreditChange: (id, value) => {
      // Cleaner way of mutating object in array
      setUserList(prevUsersList => prevUsersList.map(
        user => user.id === id ? {...user, newCredit: value} : user 
      ));
    },
    handleFocusChange: (id) => {
      console.log(id);
      setFocusedRowId(id);
    },
  },
};
```